# Update HTML table cell with mysql data rather than adding new cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

there are 2 things I'm trying to achieve both im having issues with.

the 1st is when my function runs on interval it add new cells into the table rather than updating what may currently be there already.

the 2nd, the layout of the table I'm trying to create as 10 columns across 12 rows down where the cells get limited by these measurements rather than displaying all 120 cells at once ( i have not created a CSS or script for this part yet as after looking around the internet i couldn't find a reference as to where to start.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log(1+0);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch.php',
            type: 'get',
            //type: 'post',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
                var len = response.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                  var beacon = response[i].beacon;
                  var location = response[i].location;

                  var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                  "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                  "<td align='center'> <span class='minutes'>00</span>:<span class='seconds'>00</span> </td>" +
                  "</tr>";

                  $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str); 
                }
                setInterval(updateTable, 10000);
            }
        })
    })

    function updateTable() {
        console.log(1+1);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetch.php',
            type: 'get',
            //type: 'post',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response){
                var len = response.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                  var beacon = response[i].beacon;
                  var location = response[i].location;

                  var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                  "<td align='center'>" + beacon + "</td>" +
                  "</tr>";

                  $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
                  /*( i have been told this part is the issue as to why the cells get added rather than updated but im not sure how i need to correct it to resolve this issue)*/

                }        
            }
        });
     };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first tip:

1. define a Id for row on create rows

```
var tr_str = "<tr id='"+ beacon +"'>";
```

2. So, now you can add or replace depends if exist, on update function;

```
var $table = $("#userTable tbody");
var $row = $('tr#'+beacon);

if($row.length) $row.replaceWith(tr_str);
else $table.append($newRow);
```

Comment: is it possible you could put this in context please as i have updated my code but it no longer returns any data or any errors to say whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid searching for specific HTML elements and updating them:

It's always tricky when updating HTML and especially updating specific cells of a table. The more complex your table structure becomes, the harder it is to update. If done right, it can work but it's messy.

The better approach would be to keep in memory your `data` and to regenerate your table when that `data` changes.

### Example:

```js
function generateFakeData(){
   const data = [];
   const max = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
   for(let i = 0; i < max; i++){
     const beacon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
     const location = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

     data.push({id: i, beacon, location});
   }
   return data;
}

const $table = $('#table > tbody');
const data = [];
function start(){
   //immediately load data
   fetchData();
   //load data every 10 seconds
   setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
}

function fetchData(){
  //Do ajax request here
  const response = generateFakeData();
  //On success call update data
  handleNewData(response); 
}

function handleNewData(response){
  response.forEach(({id, location, beacon})=>{
     const item = data.find(item=>item.id === id);
     //if item exists
     if(item){
        item.location = location;
        item.beacon   = beacon;
     } else {
      //item doesn't exist so add it
      data.push({id, location, beacon});
     }
  })
  
  //after data has been updated
  //update html
  updateTable();
}

function updateTable(){
  $table.html(
    data.sort((a,b)=>b.id-a.id).map(({id, location, beacon})=>{
      return `
        <tr>
          <td>${id}</td>
          <td>${location}</td>
          <td>${beacon}</td>
        </tr>
      `
    }).join("")
  );  
}

//start app
start();
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Beacon</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: due to the javascript timer I have in the function im trying not to update the table as i dont want the timer restarted